# Boost Asio deadline_timer on Android device does not get fired at the expiry time, but at a later point of time

Tags: android, c++, boost, boost-asio

We are trying to use boost asio deadline_timers on an android device. we have a requirement where we need to fire a timer every 100 msec. I have used the code as follows. However, the timer seems to be fired every 1 second. What should we fine tune in the Android system for the boost asio deadline timer to work as expected?

Note: the following code works as expected on a plain linux system. What makes it work differently on an Andorid system?

**Code**:

```
void print(asio::deadline_timer* ptimer, const asio::error_code& err)
{

 struct timeval tval;

 if(0 == gettimeofday(&tval, NULL))
 {
  std::cout <<" Timer...  sec::microsec = "<<tval.tv_sec<<"::"<<tval.tv_usec<< std::endl;
 }
 else
 {
    std::cout <<" Timer...  gettimeofday Error!" << std::endl;
 }

 ptimer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
 ptimer->async_wait(boost::bind(&print, ptimer, asio::placeholders::error));


}
```

**Output on a Android device**

```
Timer...  sec::microsec = 1298328679::39207
Timer...  sec::microsec = 1298328680::46773
Timer...  sec::microsec = 1298328681::54624
Timer...  sec::microsec = 1298328682::63861
Timer...  sec::microsec = 1298328683::65740
Timer...  sec::microsec = 1298328684::69301
Timer...  sec::microsec = 1298328685::76500
Timer...  sec::microsec = 1298328686::85768
```

Comment: do you know if asio is using the `epoll` reactor on Android?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure your android environment end up having **BOOST_DATE_TIME_HAS_HIGH_PRECISION_CLOCK** defined.

If you take a look at the default timer_traits in `boost/asio/time_traits.hpp`, you'll see that if this is not defined, asio will use the **second_clock** as its timer.

This define comes from `boost/date_time/compiler_config.hpp`, conditional on **BOOST_HAS_GETTIMEOFDAY** or **BOOST_HAS_FTIME**. Given your example, presumably the former should be defined.

I don't know if android is considered its own platform or if boost detects it as linux. In `boost/config/platform/linux.hpp` it's defined as:

```
//
// If glibc is past version 2 then we definitely have
// gettimeofday, earlier versions may or may not have it:
//
#if defined(__GLIBC__) && (__GLIBC__ >= 2)
#  define BOOST_HAS_GETTIMEOFDAY
#endif
```

This is probably where you want to add an additional condition for android.